# Enrutamiento a la carpeta src

Tags: java, html, jsp

Tengo un proyecto en NetBeans-Java Web 
[image: Este es el tipo de proyecto]

y quiero enviar datos de un formulario (login) para autenticarlos y dar acceso al sistema.

[image: Esta es la estructura del proyecto]

El formulario se encuentra en la carpeta de Web Pages y en esa carpeta puedo enrutar usando por ejemplo  href="../nombreDelArchivo.jsp" para dirigirme a otro archivo o también puedo usar la ruta absoluta, mi problema  viene cuando intento enrutar a un archivo .java en la carpeta Source Packages por ejemplo (action="../src/package/autenticacion.java")ya que no encuentra el archivo con ningun tipo de enrutamiento. Alguna idea de por que sucede ?

Comment: creo que deberia ser en el archivo jsp:
import package/autenticacion.java
Pero si quieres cargarlo como recurso:
ClassLoader cl=getClass().getClassLoader(); 
URL resourcePath=cl.getResource("package/autenticacion.java"); 
bueno en esta opción hay que probar varias rutas /src/package/autenticacion.java ó ../package/autenticacion.java

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cuando desarrollas aplicaciones web bajo Java EE, tus archivos JSP no enrutan a tus archivos Java. Tienes varias opciones:

1. Codificar todo en JSP y tener código Java embebido dentro de tu JSP. Tu JSP hace de vista y controlador de tus páginas. Esto se logra mediante scriptlets, allí puedes importar clases Java y utilizar sus miembros (métodos, atributos). Solo es útil para temas de aprendizaje. No se recomienda hacer esto en ambientes de producción.
2. Utilizar el patrón arquitectónico [Modelo Vista Controlador](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modelo%E2%80%93vista%E2%80%93controlador) (MVC por sus siglas) general, donde los archivos JSP conforman la **V**ista, utilizas Servlets para atender las peticiones HTTP y conforman el **C**ontrolador (también proveen funcionalidad de enrutador) y se apoyan en otras clases Java (POJOs, dao, etc) que conforman el **M**odelo.
3. Utilizar el patrón MVC mediante [Front Controller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Front_controller) (enlace en inglés), donde tienes un solo Servlet central (controlador único) que captura todos los requests a tu aplicación y delega el comportamiento a otras clases (modelo). Los archivos JSP son la vista de la aplicación. Este modelo se utiliza en varios frameworks como Spring MVC, JSF, Struts 2, entre otros.

Para temas de aprendizaje, agregaré un ejemplo de la opción 2 (la opción 1 es cultura general solamente y no es recomendada, por ende no la explico). Se asume que trabajas con Java EE 7 y por lo menos un contenedor de servlets de versión 3.0 como Tomcat 7 o superior.

Definimos la vista.

```
Web Pages
+ index.html
- WEB-INF
  + index.jsp
  + web.xml
```

Como puedes ver, los archivos JSP no se encuentran en web pages sino dentro de WEB-INF. La ventaja de esto es que los archivos contenidos en WEB-INF no pueden ser accedidos directamente por los usuarios, por lo que para acceder a ellos se utilizará siempre un controller, esto es, un servlet.
El archivo web.xml se define así:

```
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee 
         http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd"
         version="3.1">
    <!--
        Desde Servlets 3.0 los servlets pueden ser decorados
        con la anotación @WebServlet y no necesitan
        configurarse en el XML.
    -->

    <!--
        Se define el archivo de entrada de la aplicación.
    -->
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

El archivo index.html es solo para que la aplicación pueda funcionar. No debe tener contenido, su peso es de 0 bytes.

El archivo index.jsp:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Hola a servlets</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <!--
            Esas cosas entre ${} hacen referencia a variables
            almacenadas como atributos del request (entre otros)
            Más de esto adelante.
        -->
        <h1>Hola ${nombre}. ¡Bienvenido a tu primer Servlet!</h1>
        <form method="POST" action="index.html">
            Ingresa tu nombre:
            <input type="text" name="nombre" id="nombre" value="${nombrePorDefecto}" />
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Defines un Servlet para index.jsp:

```
@WebServlet("index.html") //se indica la ruta sobre la cual leerá las peticiones
public class IndexServlet extends HttpServlet {
    private static final String NOMBRE_POR_DEFECTO = "Missael";
    /*
        doGet se utiliza para pre procesar la vista, es decir para
        cargar información que se deberá visualizar en la vista.
        En este caso, se agregará un valor por defecto al nombre.
    */
    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {
        request.setAttribute("nombrePorDefecto", NOMBRE_POR_DEFECTO);
        //se muestra el contenido de la vista
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    /*
        doPost es para procesar una acción. En este caso
        solo se procesa el nombre ingresado por el usuario
    */
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException, ServletException {

        /*
            El método HttpServletRequest#getParameter permite
            obtener un parámetro por su nombre (<input name="nombre" />)
            no confundir con el id  (<input id="nombre" />).
        */
        String nombreIngresado = request.getParameter("nombre");
        //se agrega información a visualizar en el resultado de la vista
        request.setAttribute("nombre", nombreIngresado);
        //se vuelve a agregar el nombre por defecto.
        request.setAttribute("nombrePorDefecto", NOMBRE_POR_DEFECTO);
        //se muestra el contenido de la vista
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/index.jsp");
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
        /*
            Cuidado. El hecho de que los métodos doGet y doPost
            tengan código similar en ambos es solo una coincidencia.
            No siempre puede suceder este caso.
        */
    }
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias Luiggi estoy trabajando en ello, pero tengo una duda, soy nuevo en esto y no se si el archivo de "web.xml"  lo creaste tu o lo crea netBeans por defecto ?

Comment: Hay IDEs que lo crean. Yo elimino su contenido y lo creo desde 0.

Comment: Luiggi una pregunta, ya logre resolver mi problema, ahora tengo la siguiente duda hago la validación  de usuario pero como seria el enrutamiento a una pagina dentro de web-inf?   por que  usar algo asi como response.sendRedirect("./home/home.jsp"); no funcionara o si ?

Comment: Por favor publica otra pregunta al respecto explicando tu situación. Es muy probable que yo o alguien más pueda responderla y brindarte apoyo al respecto.